# compare 2 strings by character to find differences

Tags: java, string, binary, iterator

Was just wondering about if there was a quick way to determine @ which points in a string the elements differ. I have 2 binary strings and i want to know @ how many places they are not the same.

```
1111111100010001111011100010001011011101001100111100110001000100
0001001011001101110110000101001111111010000000010001110001000000
```

So i guess i need like a for loop and a counter but all i know of is the compare() and similar things but not how to go char by char
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

write your own implementation of a variant of [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int diff( byte [] a, byte [] b){
    int diff = 0;
    String byteAr1;
    String byteAr2;
    char A1 [];
    char A2 [];

    byteAr1 = hexToBin(a);
    byteAr2 = hexToBin(b);

    A1 = byteAr1.toCharArray();
    A2 = byteAr2.toCharArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++){
        if(A1[i] != A2[i]){
            diff++;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your strings always the same length? If so you could do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {
    if(string1.charAt(i) == string2.charAt(i))
    //the two chars are equal
}
```

If the strings are different lengths that will fail though, because you'll be trying to access characters which don't exist

Comment: Good answer.  Since these are sequences of binary numbers, I assume they represent ints shorts or longs, which are fixed-length.  If that is the case, we can assume the lengths are equal and this solution will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings to byte arrays and use the XOR (^) operator.

Count the number of 1's.